# Laravel 8 Livewire failure on IIS

Tags: laravel, iis, laravel-livewire

When trying to deploy a Laravel 8 app to an IIS environment, the app delivers an error "bootstrap\cache directory must be present and writable" when returning any blade view which contains a livewire component:

```
...
<div class="user-panel">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
             
    <livewire:company-chooser />
      
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
...
```

The bootstrap\cache directory is present and writeable. I 've done emptying Laravel caches with php artisan view:clear, config:clear, route clear without bringing any solution to the problem.

The error keeps appearing after I completely empty the contents of the livewire blade view itself, there is no error however if I remove the `<livewire:company-chooser />` element from the calling view.

In my local Valet dev environment the app works like a charm alongside with the livewire components.
I wonder if the problem has something to do with the IIS environment, but I'm not sure.
Anybody a hint?
Regards

Comment: Consider that it may be a permission issue. Please check the identity of application pool and change it to local system or other custom account which has enough permission to folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bruce! Upon your advice I changed the app pool from DefaultAppPool to the name of the app, and granted bootstrap\cache full control for most of the users. These steps solved the problem, the livewire stuff seems to be running now on IIS. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In the IIS Manager I changed the app pool from DefaultAppPool to the name of the app, and in File Explorer I granted bootstrap\cache full control for most of the users. These steps solved the problem and the livewire stuff seems to be running now on IIS.